# Finding the probability of a random variable given PMF of two variables conditioned on that variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayes-theorem

Random variables S and C, which can take values 0 and 1 have the following joint distribution:

[image]

*Taking the marginal PMFs and then multiplying, I found out that S and C are **NOT independent**.*

The conditional distribution $p_{S,C|T}(s,c|t)$, where T is a random variable which can take values 0 and 1, is shown below.

[image]

*Taking the marginal PMFs of S and C given T and then multiplying, I found out that S and C are **conditionally independent** given T.*

My question is: Is it possible to find the probability that T is zero or T is 1 from the tables above?

From Baye's Rule, $$p_T=\frac{p_{T\mid S,C}\cdot p_{S,C}}{p_{S,C\mid T}}$$ however $p_{T\mid S,C}$ is not known. Any idea?

Comment: Hint: Let $x=P(T=1)$, then $$P(S=C=0)=P(S=C=0\mid T=0)(1-x)+P(S=C=0\mid T=1)x$$

Comment: Just consider that for instance $P(S=0,C=0) = P(S=0,C=0|T=0)P(T=0) + P(S=0,C=0|T=1)P(T=1)$ (and also obviously $P(T=0) = 1-P(T=1)$).

Comment: @Did I see, thanks!